# Проблема с кодировкой после записи файла и открытия в Excell

Tags: c#, файлы, excel, кодировка, csv

Имеется `StringBuilder`, из которого мы получаем текст, который хотим записать. Но вот в чем проблема, попробовал два способа записи в файл.

Исходные данные: 
`sb`- это один и тот же `StringBuilder`
`fullFileName` - это полный путь к файлу формата ***.csv**

Первый способ:

```
var file = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
File.WriteAllBytes(fullFileName, file);
```

Второй способ:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullFileName, sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Посмотрел в **Notepad++**, первый способ записывает файл в кодировке  *«UTF8 (Без BOM)»*, а второй в *«UTF8»*. Второй файл не имеет проблем с кодировкой и все читаемо, а первый выдает кракозябру, все это при открытии в Excell. Формат файла ***.csv**. Поясните пожалуйста, в чем причина проблемы и как ее можно решить в первом способе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, в отсутствие BOM Excel не умеет автоопределить кодировку, и считает её кодировкой UTF-16. В качестве решения на стороне пользователя может подойти [это](http://artkiev.com/blog/excel-import-csv-utf-8.htm): создание чистой таблицы, и в ней импорт через «Данные» → «Из текста»: Excel распознает CSV, и предложит выбрать кодировку.

Если вы хотите записать BOM в текст: `Encoding.GetBytes` не знает, что у вас кодируется не *кусочек* текста, а *весь* текст, и не добавляет BOM. Вы можете получить BOM самостоятельно при помощи `Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()`, записать эти байты в файл, а затем уже дописывать остальное.

К сожалению, я не нашёл метода `File.AppendAllBytes`, поэтому вам придётся либо сконкатенировать байты в памяти

```
var file = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("some data");
var fileWithBom = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(file).ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(fullFileName, file);
```

(что наверное не самый эффективный метод), либо писать в два приёма:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(fullFileName))
{
    var bom = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
    stream.Write(bom, 0, bom.Length);
    var file = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("some data");
    stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
}
```

Comment: Сначала попробовал через `Union` - выдало кракозябру, а вот с `Concat` все заработало. Спасибо )

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Мне кажется, Union возвращает объединение как для множеств. А `Concat` должен работать, да.